# A pythonic way to fetch the data in the users system

Tags: python, python-2.7, django-orm, django-1.3

The schema diagram of my project can be viewed [HERE](http://i40.tinypic.com/el4mlf.jpg).

1. I have an Employee who's parent is django User.
2. The Employee is related to a Company. A Company can have many employees.
3. An Employee can have certain Tasks, and each Task has many Employees working on it. Therefore, a m2m relationship, related by a table named Emp_relatedTo_Task.

For a certain view I want to fetch all the tasks for the logged in user, the companies related to those tasks and the employees that work in those companies.

What I have achieved this far is:

```
emp = request.user.get_profile # get_profile fetches employee 

tasks_to_emp = Task.objects.filter(employee = emp).values_list("id")

user_list = EmployeeTask.objects.filter(task__in = tasks_to_emp).values_list("user")

employees = Employee.objects.filter(id__in = user_list)

company = [employee.company for employee in employees]
company = set(company)
```

This is an amateur and less efficient way of performing the task. I have looked into select_related() but this also fetches the foreignkey attributes only. Any good suggestions to do this task as efficient as possible?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention what is a `project` but assuming a project is a list of tasks:

```
emp = Employee.objects.get(id=1) # example employee

# All employees that work for the same company as this employee
company_employees = Employee.objects.filter(company=emp.company)

# List of tasks for this employee, if your FK in Employee is called `task`
emp_tasks = Employee.task_set.all() 

# The company for this employee
company = emp.company
```